# Microsoft Graph Api: accessing a sharepoint site via its web url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Having trouble at the documenation how to use Graph API to access a sharepoint via its web url.

So something like https://mycompanydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/my_site_name

Answer (score 6):

It appears what are you after is [Access a site by server-relative URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-a-site-by-server-relative-url):

> If you have the server-relative URL for a site resource, you can
>   construct a request as follows:
>
> ```
> GET /sites/{hostname}:/{server-relative-path}
> ```

In your case the request should look like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompanydomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/my_site_name:/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the weburl the safest option it to use the `shares` API.

1. Encode the URL as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#encoding-sharing-urls)
2. Use it as the shareid and request the site

Using the URL you provided in your example, the request that I would make would look like:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9teWNvbXBhbnlkb21haW4uc2hhcmVwb2ludC5jb20vc2l0ZXMvbXlfc2l0ZV9uYW1l/site

Comment: Hi Brad. What is the difference between a web url and server-relative url?

Comment: A server relative URL doesn't include the host, but is relative to it (e.g. /sites/foo), whereas a web URL is something can can be pasted in the browser and used directly (e.g. https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/foo). Realistically you can think of weburl = host + server relative url

Comment: could you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009982/microsoft-graph-api-java-sdk-get-a-site-with-its-server-relative-url