# Microsoft Graph API Java SDK: Get a site with its server relative url

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Java SDK for Graph API.

I want to access a site via its server relative path like

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/company.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/

I can only find in the SDK something for find by ID apposed to relative path? I dont have the ID

The URL of my site is like this https://mycompanydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/my_site_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution  was actually to do sites.byId("company.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:").buildRequest().get();

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the root of the relative path and then navigate from it using the path you have. So something like:

```
sites.byId("company.sharepoint.com").getByPath("/sites/mysite").buildRequest().get();
```

This should result in a request to Graph that looks like the one you specified.

Comment: So I can get a regular http request to work like this GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/my_site_name:/

Comment: However with the SDK i have tried mGraphServiceClient.sites().byId("mycompany.sharepoint.com:").getByPath("/sites/my_site_name:").buildRequest().get(); gives a bad request error. removing the : after my_Site_name gives a cannot find this resource error

Comment: weburl of my site is added to original post

Comment: removing : from both hostname and path results in bad request too